# su commands in a script executed as root seem inconsistent

Tags: linux, bash, unix, su, quoting

I'm trying to understand how to run commands from my user account in a script with root privileges. I've got this test script and the output is confusing me.

~$ cat test.sh

**output**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
su -c "whoami" user
su -c "echo $HOME" user
```

~$ sudo ./test.sh

**output**:

```
user
/root
```

Why does the first 'su' command seem to run as 'user' but the second seems to run as 'root'?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [Pass arguments to a command run by another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156343/56041), [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118433/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/); [How do I use a Bash variable (string) containing quotes in a command?](https://superuser.com/q/360966/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), etc,

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes expand shell variables. Try

```
echo su -c "echo $HOME" user
```

to see what I mean. It's the shell running the script that expands `$HOME`, which runs as root (from `sudo ./test.sh`). So what ends up being run is `su -c 'echo /root' user`.

You want

```
su -c 'echo $HOME' user
```

Here we pass `echo $HOME` unexpanded to `su -c`.